# Highlight Row in a Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML/jQuery code and am trying to highlight a row in my table when a checkbox is clicked, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it going.

See code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<tr>
  <td class="t12datavalue" align="center" style=""><input type="checkbox" value="123" name="f01"></td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">123</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">333</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">Alex</td>
  <td class="t12datavalue" style="">Smith</td>
</tr>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
             $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
        } else if($(this).parent().is('.highlight')) {
             $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** [The request by tonsils](http://jsfiddle.net/RRmJs/7/).

**Edit:** [Box9 topped this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494021/highlight-row-in-a-table/5494134#5494134) anyway.  Clever devil.

Take a look-see at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRmJs/4/).  Bam, we have color highlighting and sweet, short jQuery.

In case you don't want to click, here's the aforementioned sexy jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td :checkbox').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you see my question below under moe - would also like to apply this to a checkAll process. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A refinement on the ideas in other answers:

```
$('td :checkbox').bind('change click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
}).change();
```

The reason I bind to both `change` and `click` events is because `change` incorrectly fires after the checkbox loses focus in IE, while `click` doesn't trigger on keyboard events.

I use `.toggleClass` [with a switch](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) so that the highlight is guaranteed to be in sync with the checkbox state, despite the handler being triggered twice (once from `change`, once from `click`).

Finally, I immediately trigger the `change` event so that the classes are correctly applied on DOM ready.

Comment: +1 for upping me.  Not often that happens.  I didn't know about the IE bug though.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Just realised you are Australian... awesome :)

Comment: Thanks @alex and @Levi. @alex, I noticed a while ago you're a Queenslander :)

Comment: Also want to say thanks for your solution as well. Still trying to get my head around it though but I won't give up.

Answer (score 1):

#### jQuery

```
$('td :checkbox').change(function() {
    var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (this.checked){
       parentTr.addClass('highlight');
    } else {
       parentTr.removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

There shouldn't be any need to explicitly check if the class is on the `tr`, the `removeClass()` will silently fail if the class isn't present.

I considered suggesting `toggleClass()`, ([all these answers are wrong, apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494021/highlight-row-in-a-table/5494110#5494110)), but I was just covering the edge case if any of these checkboxes were either set on default or programmatically checked, then it would be out of sync (and I forgot about the second argument :P).

However, [box9 has the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494021/highlight-row-in-a-table/5494134#5494134), so vote it. :)

#### CSS

```
tr.highlight td {
    background: yellow;
}
```

A `tr`'s `background` is not visible, you must apply it to the child `td`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/FruQ5/).

Comment: There's no need to add and remove, just toggle, bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
             $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').addClass('highlight');
        } else {
             $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also have a checkAll routine that will select and de-select all checkbox rows. How can I apply this to my checkAll routine which is as follows:     $("#checkAll").click(function() {
      $("input[name='f01']").attr('checked', 
                                $('#checkAll').is(':checked'));
    });

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is that your `<tr>` is not in a `<table>`. If you add that, it works perfectly.

P.S. I'd replace `$(this).parent().parent()` with `$(this).parents("tr")`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parents("tr").addClass('highlight');
    } else if($(this).parents("tr").is('.highlight')) {
      $(this).parents("tr").removeClass('highlight');
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I'd hope that example above just omitted that fact :)

Comment: Well, it didn't work before I added it and did after I added it, so…

Comment: `$(this).parents("tr")` may as well be `$(this).closest("tr")` Also... no need to remove and add classes, just use `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to follow your example above, you're actually missing an additional parent():

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
             $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
        } else if($(this).parent().parent().parent().is('.highlight')) {
             $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }); 
  });

NOTE: you could use the .html() jquery function on an element to determine what they contained. In my case, I used this:

alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().html());